# Situationally specific cancan roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

```
:user has_many :books
:book belongs_to :user
:book has_many :contributions
:user has_many :contributions
:contribution belongs_to :book
:contribution belongs_to :user
```

I want to be able to control behaviour in /books/show depending on whether the user is a contributor to the book. In cancan I'm aiming to have something like -

```
can :contribute, Book if @book.contributions.include?(user_id)
```

That line of code is wrong, (undefined method `contributions' for nil:NilClass) but is there a right way of putting it, or am I trying to cram to much into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining abilities you should be using [hash of conditions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions) or [block of code](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks). In your case this should work:

```
can :contribute, Book do |book|
  book.contributions.include?(user_id)
end
```

Then when you define your authorisation in controller or view, like stated in [readme](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#2-check-abilities--authorization), you can pass `@book` variable which will be passed to block in you ability definition like:

```
authorize! :contribute, @book
```

or

```
<% if can? :contribute, @book %>
```